# How to install ImageMagick in windows?

Tags: image, imagemagick, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install imagemagick on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036847/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-windows-7)

Hi I just install image magick as per the php.net description. but its doesnt working well. It always shows this error

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in C:...\imgborder.php on line XXX

why this error happening. I restarted my webserver. but it still showing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with php extension, just use imagemagick as a console utility using `exec()`. It's way more flexible.