# How do I rotate an animated gif using PHP?

Tags: php, rotation, animated-gif

Is there any code out there that will allow me to rotate an animated gif 180 degrees while still maintaining the animation?

I tried using the standard [imagerotate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) function (changing the appropriate things from jpeg to gif), but it still only outputs the first frame.

I also found https://stackoverflow.com/a/9356895/462158, but I would like to find something other than ImageMagick if at all possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with ImageMagick?

Comment: and what do you like to find then, if not ImageMagik. Implementing it directly in PHP or what?

Comment: if you read the comment on PHP site for imagerotate, a CSS rotate alternative is given

Comment: GD doesn't support animated gifs.

Comment: As far as not using ImageMagick, I should have reworded it to say something like "I didn't want to have to install anything to get this to work."  I have nothing against ImageMagick.

Comment: And, Waygood, I'm not sure why my mind didn't go to CSS in the beginning, but that worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [ImageMagick rotateImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.rotateimage.php), as suggested in the comments

OR

1. Extract frames from the gif
2. Process individual frames the way you like (imagerotate in your case..)
3. Reconstruct animation

To extract frames from gif image (and reconstruct the animation), you can use [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) for example.

The first way is simpler, so first try that, but in case it does not fit the need somehow, processing manually is always an option