# Configuring Imagick for PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I want to configure Imagick for PHP, but don't know how.  I have all these great tutorial sites for learning how to configure the two, but I get confused when I read the directions.  I'm not very good with using Command Prompt, so it adds to my confusion when a direction says something like:

Go to imagick folder and type "phpize && ./configure && make && make install"

**or**

In the root PHP source directory run ./buildconf –force to rebuild the configuration script

I'd like to know if someone could explain to me how to configure PHP with Imagick, but explain it with clear directions that a non-technical user can follow.

Below are the tutorial websites, which I'm currently using:

http://www.ioncannon.net/php/75/how-to-compile-imagemagick-for-php-by-hand/
http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=26443

So far, I've installed a binary release of ImageMagick & I've download + unzipped MagickWandForPHP-1.0.9-2

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On what platform/Os are you trying to configure Imagemagick and PHP?

Comment: windows, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Not using windows since...., but if I remember correctly look in c:/php/ LOOK FOR php.ini and add this extension=php_imagick.dll

edit:

found this.. 
http://www.elxsy.com/2009/07/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-and-using-with-php-imagick/

and this for windows7
[How to install Imagick/imagemagick on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036847/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-windows-7)

Comment: What do I do with MagicWant for PHP?  if I add extension to php.ini will php automatically know that I'm adding Magick

Comment: create a file info.php with the following code `<?
    phpinfo(); ?> ` you should be able to find it somewhere in php and as for MagicWant "In order to use the MagickWand For PHP module's functions, you need to install ImageMagick version 6.3.5, or greater, and the MagickWand for PHP extension source code / DLL. " http://www.magickwand.org/download/php/

Comment: Glad i could help :) [closed]

Comment: Wait, I have one last question.  When I added extension to php.ini I got "specific module could not be found".  Does this mean that PHP cannot find MagicWandforPHP?  I currently have an unzipped MagicWandforPHP folder in the ext folder, but I don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: Have not tried it out, 1) Does ImageMagick appear in phpinfo ? ifso Download the package MagickWand, it should hold something like a readme file .. also see this page. http://lsces.co.uk/wiki/index.php?page=PHP+Extension+Magickwand (for ImageMagick installation look at my answer, and take a look at How to install imagemagick on windows7 )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27601/discussion-between-japerk14-and-grmn)