# I have install ImageMagick still i face error in image library

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick

I want to use imageMagick for image processing. Now I have installed ImageMagick `ImageMagick-6.8.4-10-Q16-x64-dll.exe` but still I face the following error:

```
Image processing failed. Please verify that your server supports the chosen protocol and that the path to your image library is correct.
```

My code is -

```
$config = array();
$config['image_library'] = 'ImageMagick';
$config['source_image'] = $file;
$config['new_image'] =  $file;
$config['library_path'] = '/usr/local/bin';
$config['create_thumb']    = FALSE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']     = 50;
$config['height']   = 50;
$this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
 if ( !$this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo "resize -".$this->image_lib->display_errors();
        } 
        $this->image_lib->clear();
```

Comment: Before posting this type of question it would be helpful if you give information about your development environment.

Comment: for [windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036847/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-windows-7), [xp](http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/imagemagick/imagemagick.html), [Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/163818/how-to-install-rmagick-on-ubuntu-10-04). After instillation it would better to restart the `web server`.

Answer (score 0):

Wait. I assumed you are using Windows (as you installed .exe ), but your path is a Linux path (`/usr/local/bin`). Double check your installation path.

Comment: what is the windows path ?

Comment: You installed the program, but you don't know the installation path?

Comment: Did you follow this instructions to install ? http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

Answer (score 0):

Below has given me expected result. Hope you will also get same.

```
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    //For resizing of image in size of dilog
    $config['image_library']  = 'ImageMagick';
    $config['library_path'] = 'C:\\ImageMagick\\';

    $config['source_image'] = $source_filepath;
    $config['new_image'] = $new_filepath;

    $config['width'] = 128;
    $config['height'] = 128;
    $config['quality'] = '100%';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    if (! $this->image_lib->resize()) {
        $error_msg = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        print_r($error_msg);
    }
    else {
        echo "Done";
    }
```

Here

```
$config['library_path'] = 'C:\\ImageMagick\\';
```

is the path for windows where your imageMagick application is installed.(Try to install in such a folder to which we can easily fingd the path upto it).
Change the image library to :

```
$config['image_library']  = 'ImageMagick';
```

& other all configuration is remains same.