# Imagick is not installed

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I'm currently using UniServerz, trying to install ImageMagick and IMagick so i can try doing some image resizing on php since i've read that GD isn't as good and wasn't supported anymore.i've had a look on [How to install Imagick/imagemagick on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036847/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-windows-7?rq=1) and followed what was written in there.

Specifically, i've installed ImageMagick through the dll.exe and copied the php_imagick.dll into the extensions folder, followed by adding extension=php_imagick.dll in the php.ini file.The permissions for the folder have also been checked, and they are all set to full control.

However,when i try to execute the code

```
<?php

if(extension_loaded('imagick')) {
    echo 'Imagick Loaded';
}
else
{
    echo "Not loaded";
}
?>
```

i keep getting "Not loaded" on the screen, and i don't know what else must i do to install imagick so that i can use ImageMagick on php.

Would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Does phpinfo show you information about ImageMagick? Have you made sure to use the right php.ini if there is more than one? (Check your php.ini path in phpinfo output). Are there any messages in your error_log?

Comment: the only thing in phpinfo that is related to imagick shows "--with-imagick=shared" , there are no error messages in the apache error log. I've also edited the php.ini files(all of them) just in case.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I came across this problem too. It's not just the one php_imagick.dll that needs to be deployed. You need to deploy all DLL files that start with CORE_RL or IM_MOD_RL, and save them to the PHP root directory (where you have php.exe), or to a directory in your PATH variable. Once I did that, it worked like a charm.

See this reference:
https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html

Answer (score 0):

Besides my points already mentioned in the comments, hace you already checked the the php manual on specific windows dll problems?

> Common problems are the location of the DLL, **the value of the " extension_dir" setting** inside php.ini and **compile-time setting mismatches**.
>
> If the problem lies in a compile-time setting mismatch, you probably didn't download the right DLL. Try downloading again the extension with the right settings. Again, phpinfo() can be of great help.

Source:
http://www.php.net/manual/de/install.pecl.windows.php#install.pecl.windows.problemsolving