# Install Imagick on Windows/Wamp

Tags: php, windows, wamp, imagick

I encounter problems to install Imagick on Windows using Wamp.

I tried to install differents version ,I've followed differents tutorials like :

[How to install Imagick/imagemagick on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036847/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-windows-7) Or https://refreshless.com/blog/imagick-pecl-imagemagick-windows/  but it still does not work.

When i check my PHP/extensions on wamp i can see that Imagick is green checked but i have a warning which tells me that extension is not added on php.ini (extension=php_imagick.dll).

[image]

This is my php.ini :

[image]

Someone have any solution?
in advance Thanks.

Comment: What is the path of the `php.ini` file you posted?

Comment: C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\bin