# Installing imagick on wampserver 3.0.6

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver, imagick

I have downloaded `php_imagick-3.4.3-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip` from there

> http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.4.3/windows

Unzip and copy `php_imagick.dll` to the `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext` (I'm using PHP version 5.6.25)

Then I have added `extension=php_imagick.dll` in the `wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.ini`

restarted server and go to the PHPInfo. imagick section did not appear

Then I added `extension=php_imagick.dll` in the `wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\php.ini`
have restarted server and got the same result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036847/how-to-install-imagick-imagemagick-on-windows-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was solved by installation of another version ImageMagic: `ImageMagick-6.9.8-5-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Also to add, in case anyone else needs it, you need the corresponding **Thread Safe** or **Non-Thread Safe** verison of imagemagick.

To find out which version of PHPyou have, use [phpinfo();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and search for the entry called '**Thread Safety**', which will be enabled if it's thread safe.