# Is possible run ImageMagick version PORTABLE from PHP 7 over Windows?

Tags: imagemagick, portability

We can install ImageMagick and run with PHP following this instructions:

[How to install Imagick/imagemagick PHP extension on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036847)

but... Some idea about how we can run **ImageMagick version PORTABLE** over Windows with PHP ?

... really I never install Apache, MySQL or PHP, samplely I download the version ZIP:

- httpd-2.4.33-win64-VC15.zip
- php-7.2.5-Win32-VC15-x64.zip
- mysql-5.7.28-winx64.zip

by years I use this "WAMP portable" and never I need install nothing. (me only install Sublime Text... xD)

Please: is possible run [ImageMagick-7.0.9-4-**portable**-Q16-x64.zip](https://imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-7.0.9-4-portable-Q16-x64.zip) from PHP and not install?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the portable version of ImageMagick by calling [popen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to execute a CLI command, but you can not use PHP's Imagick extension as that requires linking to the ImageMagick libraries (no included with portable).

Comment: Thanks; then for I can run "*http://localhost/createimage.php*" **in windows** my unique option is **install** from .exe to ImageMagick ??